# I'm trying to check if two column's specific values in a db table exist in the same row

Tags: python, django

Essentially I'm trying to make sure that both of the values the two columns have exist in a row. If they do I'll return a True boolean value. Just unclear on the logic to do the check itself.

Comment: You might get better answers if you provide your models, but I think what you need are [Q](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q) expressions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.